# Html5 pushState not Trigger shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, pushstate, uiwebviewdelegate

When h5 using `location.href` to go to other url, the following delegate api will be called. But it doesn't work when h5 using `pushState`. Why this happen? And how can I know when the h5 change its content at this time?

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any answer?

Comment: @pista329 u can try to rewrite the pushState function and fire an event in it to notify native throuht jsbridge.